# How to implement ng-if correctly with more then 1 expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, angular-material

I have this list of users and when you click on a user then a popup box shows. In this popup box you will see the user's name and a color picker. Note that when you log in just as a user you only can click on your name in the list and then the popup box will show. When you log in as an admin, you can click on any user to see the popup box. In this popup box the admin gets to see the user's name and has the option to delete the selected user. For the moment in the popup box of the admin there is also a color picker.

What I am trying to achieve now is that when you log in as a admin can can see the popup box for every user with his name and option to delete that user (so I need to hide the colorpicker). The kicker is that the color picker has to be visible to the currently logged in user (whether that is an admin or a user).

I hope my explanation is clear and some one can help me out.

I am able to logged the user's role id as well as the user id

Part of my code for the popup box (color picker section):

```
<div class="colorPickerWrapper" ng-if="user._id==activeUser && role._id ==currentRole">
       <div ng-repeat="color in colors" ng-style="{'background-color': color}"  
       class="color-tile" ng-click="pickColor(color)"></div>
</div>
```

Part of my app.js code:

```
//START CONTROLLER
angular.module('zazzleToolPlannerApp')
    .controller('CalendarCtrl', function ($scope, $mdDialog, $http, $rootScope, $timeout, User, Auth, UserService, TaskService) {
        $scope.isAdmin = Auth.isAdmin;
        $scope.getCurrentUser = Auth.getCurrentUser;

        $scope.currentRole = $scope.getCurrentUser().role_id;
        console.log('%%%%%%%555555 currentRole', $scope.currentRole);

        $scope.activeUser = $scope.getCurrentUser()._id;
        console.log('????????????  logging active/current user id', $scope.activeUser);

});
```

Here is a visual of the an admin logged in with the popup box still with the color picker. As you can see in the console I am loggin the user and role id -> [image]

I know that this bit of code is not correct

```
ng-if="user._id==activeUser && role._id==currentRole"
```

When I run the application now with this bit of code from above then the popup box has no colorpicker (whether I am logged in as a user or admin)

Comment: try checking if mabe one of the compared values is a string, and the other one is an integer, and then they might not equal

Comment: `role._id` from where you are getting it to compare? i don't see in the code and even in the dependencies.

Comment: @Jai: role._id is just a reference to my user model where i state that role_id = String and then i just access the role id like so role._id through my application where i need it

Comment: @GY22 if i have to write anything like that i would do it in my controller to produce a boolean and then i would refer it to the `ng-if="isUserAdmin"`.

Comment: @Jai: i wanted to make sure that there was something in user._id and role._id so i did in the view this  {{user._id}} , {{role._id}} -> https://gyazo.com/ddb883b0d9a99e77a7ef689b93db2f70. As you can see role._id is returning nothing ... i guess there lies the problem just not sure how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

you can use ternary expression

```
ng-if="(user._id==activeUser && role._id==currentRole)?true:false"
```

Comment: mmm this does not seem to work the popup still comes back with out a color picker even when i click on the user (who is logged in as admin -> only admin can see the color picker for himself not for the other users)